# screen -dm: "Cannot identify account"

Tags: gnu-screen

I am trying to create a new `screen` so that the screen is detached at first, and its current folder is `cd /home`.

When I execute `screen -dm "cd /home"` (the parameter `-dm` [means](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) "Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it".) I get the error message:

```
Cannot identify account 'cd '.`
```

However, when I execute `screen -dm "$(cd /home)"`, there is no error message, but the current folder in the created screen isn't `/home`.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter

```
screen -dm "$(cd /home)"
```

is substituted by the shell to get the message from `CDPATH` which shows which directory was reached by the `cd` command.  But the `cd` command only applies to the subshell, and not the command-line that `screen` sees.

The former is not substituted, and `screen` does not know what to do with a directory named "**`cd /home`**"

Perhaps you meant something like this (no quotes):

```
    screen -dm cd /home
```

which fits into the pattern listed in the manual page:

```
screen [ -options ] [ cmd [ args ] ]
```